# Filter XML by attribute value

Tags: xml, filtering, limiting

I'm working on a XML file which contains all our customers. Its an xml containing thousands of customers. I want to filter the XML and only keep customers of segment B. See code which simplifies our XML, but gives you an idea.

```
<customer>
<Name>Customer 1</Name>
<Segment>A</Segment>
</customer>
<customer>
<Name>Customer 2</Name>
<Segment>B</Segment>
</customer>
```

I dont need to make changes, I just need to remove all customers from the XML where segment is not B.

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to achieve this? Perhaps there is software available, perhaps with Visual basic or any other option.

Thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: Which platform/language are you using?

Comment: In XML terminology, your sample doesn't have any attributes at all (that would be `<customer segment="A">...</customer>`) but has only elements with text nodes. As for filtering, use XPath/XQuery/XSLT, for instance.